# Angular 2 how to Chain Observable Array to another observable array

Tags: angular, typescript, angular2-observables

I'm Trying to chain a few http calls together in angular 2. I get an array of environments with one call. And for each of those environments I want to return another array. and create an objects like

firstObject[{name:"name",secondObject[stuff,stuff2],name:"name2",secondObject[stuff,stuff2]]

However when I try to use a for loop in the array, something with the lazy nature of the subscribe makes it hard to iterate through each object. i seems to be the same on each of the second subscribes. I have output below the code. Any help would be appreciated.

```
getEnvironments(app:string){
this.loading = true;
console.log("calling get Environments")
 this._appModelService.getEnvironments(app).subscribe(val => 
  {this.environments = val;
    for(var i = 0; i < this.environments.length;++i){
      console.log("Environment name =       "+this.environments[i].EnvName);
         this._appModelService.getAppTypes(app,this.environments[i].EnvName)
      .subscribe(typeVal => 
      {
        console.log("Subscribing to i = "+i);
        console.log(typeVal);
      }

      )
    }

    this.loading = false;
  },

  err => {
  console.log("Something went wrong in get apps");                              // Log errors if any
  console.log(err);
  this.loading = false;

});

  }
```

**Out Below**

```
calling get Environments
app-model.component.ts:93 Environment name = CRT       
app-model.component.ts:93 Environment name = DRP       
app-model.component.ts:93 Environment name = IFT       
app-model.component.ts:93 Environment name = PRD       
app-model.component.ts:93 Environment name = PRE       
app-model.component.ts:93 Environment name = TRN       
app-model.component.ts:97 Subscribing to i = 6
app-model.component.ts:98 [Object, Object, Object]
app-model.component.ts:97 Subscribing to i = 6
app-model.component.ts:98 [Object, Object, Object]
app-model.component.ts:97 Subscribing to i = 6
app-model.component.ts:98 [Object, Object, Object]
app-model.component.ts:97 Subscribing to i = 6
app-model.component.ts:98 [Object, Object, Object]
app-model.component.ts:97 Subscribing to i = 6
app-model.component.ts:98 [Object, Object, Object]
app-model.component.ts:97 Subscribing to i = 6
app-model.component.ts:98 [Object, Object]
```

**Edit** 
The out put of my first call should look like this<

```
[ { EnvName: 'CRT       ' },
{ EnvName: 'DRP       ' },
{ EnvName: 'IFT       ' },
{ EnvName: 'PRD       ' },
{ EnvName: 'PRE       ' },
{ EnvName: 'TRN       ' },
```

And the output of the second Call will be

```
[ { ServerTypeName: 'App       ' },
{ ServerTypeName: 'Oracle    ' },
{ ServerTypeName: 'Weblogic  ' } ]
```

I want to combine those into a nested object.

Comment: Could you be clearer on the source data that you're getting and the output that you want?  A big part of using observables well is knowing how to use your operators to transform one observable into another. So, at first glance, it seems like that's something you'd want to do in this situation - map your source observable to your result observable. But it's hard to understand how to guide you without understanding what the source is and what the result should be

Comment: And FYI, as a general rule, if you have nested subscribes, it's usually an indication that you might not be using the power that observables give you

Comment: I added the result of those objects

Comment: Just for clarity, can you give your example output based on your sample inputs?

Comment: Ultimately I just formatted the object in the middle teir to not need to have to make multiple calls. I would have needed and array of one observable, make a subscribe to each of those observables and in each of those have another Observable array. So I figured it was better to handle this somewhere else in than the front end.

Answer (score 2):

Can we see the code for the service?

You should be chaining like

```
    this._appModelService.getEnvironments(app).subscribe(
        res => {
            // data returned from response
            // after data is returned/was a success
            this._appModelService.someOtherCall().subscribe()
        },
        err {},
        ()
    )
```

If you need to use the same data or mix data, in the service, you need to use a flatMap to chain different http requests.

Answer (score 0):

If anyone still needs a solution to the same problem as described above. Try using a `forkJoin`.

```
getEnvironments(app:string): Observable<any> {
  this._appModelService.getEnvironments(app)
  .pipe(
    //convert getEnvironments into...
    mergeMap((environments:any[]) => {
      //a join of multiple getAppTypes observables
      return forkJoin(
        environments.map(env => this._appModelService.getAppTypes(app, env.EnvName).pipe(
          map(typeVal => {
            return {/* an optional way to combine `env` and `typeVal` */}
          })
        ))
      ).pipe(
        map((typeVals:any[]) => { //post formatting to compile response object
          return {/* a way to combine all the responses */}
        })
      )
    })
  )
}
```